# How to print numbers from 1 to n using recrsion in java

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void increase(int N){
    int a = 1;

    if(b <= N) {
        System.out.print(a + " ");
        a++;
    } else {
        increase(N);                
    }
}
```

I can see the problem with this approach that the int a gets initialized to `1` every time the code goes for a recursive call. Can anyone suggest the correct solution?

Comment: pass `a` as parameter to `increase`

Comment: different solution: `void increase(int n) { if (n > 0) { increase(n-1);  System.out.println(n); } }` call it with the final number, e.g. `increase(5)` to print `1 2 3 4 5` (one number per line)

Answer (score 1):

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        increase(10,1);
    }
    private static  void increase(int N,int begin){

        if(begin <= N){
            System.out.print(begin+" ");
            begin=begin+1;
            increase(N,begin);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one additional `private` method to count current value.

```java
public static void increase(int N) {
    increase(1, N);
}

private static void increase(int a, int N) {
    if (a <= N) {
        if (a > 1)
            System.out.print(' ');

        System.out.print(i);
        increase(a + 1, N);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't compile due to a typo - either the method call should be `increase(1, N)` or the method name of the private method should be `private static void printNumbers(...)`.

Comment: @maloomeister got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `a` outside the function:

```
// I don't know your class
private a = 1;

static void increase(int N){
        
    int a = 1;
    if(b <= N){
        System.out.print(a+" ");
        a=a+1;
    
        
    }
    else
    {
        increase(N);                
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void increase(int N, int a){
    if (a>N) return;
    System.out.print(a+" ");
    a=a+1;
    increase(N,a);
}

//example call from static context print 1-100
increase(100,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
increase(10);
}

public static void increase(int a){
if(a == 11)
return;

System.out.println(a);
increase(a+1);
}
```

Comment: this should just print `10` (and the question is not exactly new)

Comment: You did not test this or you misunderstood the question. Please test easily testable code when submitting answers.